# RestKit sideload JSON association without CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to get RestKit to use some sideloaded associations in my JSON, the JSON looks like the following:

```
{
    "companies": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "420...",
            "street": "420 Kush St.",
            "city": "Seattle",
            "state": "WA",
            "zip_code": "12345"
        }
    ],
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "test@example.com",
        "token": "1234567890",
        "company_id": 1
    }
}
```

I am not using the CoreData integration and need the company attribute of my user to fill in with the company found in the "companies" key of the above JSON. My current user mapping looks like:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[GBUser class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"id": @"userId",
                                              @"email": @"email"
                                              }];

NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
return [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"/api/v0/me" keyPath:@"user" statusCodes:statusCodes];
```

Comment: Have you read this ? https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#relationships

Comment: Yes, that example uses a nested JSON representation, which I have working in multiple places. I need this foreign key relationship to map properly, which I have also seen how to do using the CoreData integration, but not without.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to write a couple of lines of code in the success block to associate the objects in the mapping result. You would use 2 response descriptors to map the users and companies separately and then combine them after the mapping has completed.